# How to interpret Difference-in-Difference results?

Tags: r, difference-in-difference

The R code used was:

```
didreg <- ln(LCR ~ Group + Time + Group * Time, data = data)
```

The two dummy variables are `Time` and `Group`. In the model, `Time` indicates the time when the treatment started. So, the years before the treatment, 2012–2014 will have a value of 0 and the years after, 2016–2018 a value of 1. The second dummy variable, `Group`, identifies the group which is exposed to the treatment. In this case, bigger banks are expected to have experienced more changes after the introduction of the regulation. As such, big banks take the value 1, while smaller banks have a value of 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this coefficient by coefficient.

### Intercept

The `(Intercept)` term is the intercept for the reference group.  In this instance, we estimate it to be approx 0.09.  The null hypothesis for the associated test is that the intercept is 0, and we reject the null.

### Time

This is the effect of time for the reference group, or alternatively, it is the slope of the reference group line.  The null hypothesis for this test is that the slope is 0, and we fail to reject the null in this case.  We can not determine if time had an effect on the reference group.

### Group

This describes the difference in the intercept for the intervention group.  The intercept for the intervention group is `Group + (Intercept)`.  The null is that the intervention group has the same intercept as the reference group (alternatively, that `Group = 0`).  We fail to reject the null for this test, so we can not conclude that the intervention group had a different intercept.

### Group:Time

This is the effect on the slope for the intervention group.  The intervention group's slope is then `Time + Time:Group`.  Like the other tests, the null is that this is 0, or alternatively that the intervention group has the same slope as the reference group.